# pickle.PicklingError: Cannot pickle files that are not opened for reading

Tags: pyspark, pickle, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm getting this error while running PySpark job on Dataproc. What could be the reason?

This is the stack trace of error.

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
  self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", 
  line 553, in save_reduce
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
  f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
  self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
  save(v)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
  f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", 
  line 582, in save_file
  pickle.PicklingError: Cannot pickle files that are not opened for reading
```

Comment: I'm getting same issue in pyspark. @ramanand Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Yes, i was reading a dictionary in map function which i haven't  broadcasted .So reason was  worker node could not find that dictionary and throws pickle exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that I was using a dictionary in the Map function.
The reason it was failing: worker nodes couldn't access the dictionary which I was passing in map function.

Solution:

```
I broadcasted the dictionary and then used it in function (Map)
sc =  SparkContext()
lookup_bc = sc.broadcast(lookup_dict)
```

Then in function, I took value by using this:

```
data = lookup_bc.value.get(key)
```